# boolean expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Construct a circuit for the boolean expression

[image: Construct a circuit for the boolean expression]

I am having issues on how to start this. Not sure if we do a graph that we put the 1 or 0 depending on the not x or not y

Comment: Presumably you are given AND, OR, and NOT logic gates. So the task is to connect those up in the right way, so that with $x$ and $y$ on the input, you get $(xy'+(x'y)')'$ on the output. So, for example, the last gate that you use should be a NOT gate, that negates the $xy'+(x'y)'$ signal, and to get that signal, you have to use an OR gate, etc.....

Comment: @Bram28 the $+$ is a xor here, not an or

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what is your source on this? Normally $+$, $\lor$, or $||$ is used for OR and $\oplus$ and $\veebar$ are used for XOR

Comment: @vera  Is the $+$ an OR or an XOR?

Comment: @Azulflame Maybe the OP should explain. $x+y$ is logical if you substitute $0,1$ mod 2 then it's an xor. See how Boolean algebras are made from Boolean rings. In the theory of Boolean functions $+$ for XOR is quite standard.

Comment: @vera Are you allowed to simplify the expression, or do you have to build the circuit analogous to the formula as given?

Comment: I agree with @Bram28.  $+$ is to be taken as inclusive or, whereas $\oplus$ is to be taken to mean exclusive or.

Comment: from what he told me its a circuit

Comment: i was going to simplify but wasnt sure if thats what he meant by circuit

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} \overline {x\bar y + \overline{\bar x y}}& = \overline{ x\bar y} \cdot \bar xy\tag{DeMorgan's Law} \\ \\
&=(\bar x + y)\cdot \bar x y \tag{DeMorgan's Law}\\ \\
& = \bar x \bar x y+( y\bar x y)\tag{Distributive Law}\\ \\
&= \bar x y + \bar xy \tag {absorption} \\ \\
& = \bar x y\tag{absorption}\\ \\
  \end{align}$$

Hence you need only a NOT gate, and an AND gate.

See Wolfram Alpha for the associated circuit:

[image]

Comment: That's a good simplification, but I think the OP is looking for a circuit for the formula as is ... I could be wrong though, I'll ask

Comment: Only correct if + = OR.

Comment: Note my comment below your comment (below the question).  I've taken "+" to mean OR (inclusive OR) , and if it applied here (which it does not), "$\oplus$" to mean XOR (the exclusive OR).

Comment: Thank you, @Bram28, for your back-handed compliment. The logical formulae are equivalent, hence, I see no reason not to create a circuit most efficiently.

Comment: @amWhy True, and in practice it's certainly good for the OP to always ask the question to see if an expression can be simplified!

Comment: Thanks, @Bram28.

Comment: @Bram28 yes im looking for the circuit for the formula, sorry i was looking for some more info

Comment: at first i did simplify but i didnt think thats what he wanted. so then i found some graphs

Answer (score 1):

While you could just mock up a representation of the circuit then simplify, you could also solve and simplify the equation given.

Starting with $\overline{x\overline{y}+\overline{\overline{x}y}}$, apply [DeMorgan's Theorum](http://capone.mtsu.edu/phys2020/Lectures/L19-L25/L3/DeMorgan/body_demorgan.html)

$\overline{(x\overline{y}) }\cdot\overline{\overline{(\overline{x}y)}}$

Removing the double negation on the second half, and applying DeMorgan's Theorum to the first half:

$ (\overline{x} + \overline{\overline{y}})\cdot (\overline{x}y) $

Removing the double negation:

$(\overline{x} + y) \cdot (\overline{x} \cdot y)$

Distributing the AND along the OR we get:

$\overline{x}\cdot\overline{x} \cdot y + y\cdot y \cdot \overline{x}$

Removing duplicates in the ANDs, we get:

$\overline{x} \cdot y + \overline{x} \cdot y$

Which simplifies to:

$\overline{x}\cdot y$

Which is just an AND gate, with the X input inverted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $+$ denotes XOR then: $\overline{x\overline{y} + \overline{\overline{x}y}} = 1 + x\overline{y} + \overline{\overline{x}y} = 1 + x\overline{y} + 1 + \overline{x}y = x\overline{y} + \overline{x}y$

Now what gates do we have at our disposal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to the formula as is, here is the circuit generated by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logic%20circuit%20~((x%20and%20~y)%20or%20~(~x%20and%20y)%20)):

[image]

One thing you can do is to just have one $x$ and one $y$ on thew left, but to split them as required by the diagram.